# split a string which consists decimals instead of integer

Tags: php, regex

I split a string '3(1-5)' like this:

```
$pattern = '/^(\d+)\((\d+)\-(\d+)\)$/';
preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
```

But I need to do the same thing for decimals, i.e. '3.5(1.5-4.5)'.
And what do I have to do, if the user writes '3,5(1,5-4,5)'?

Output of '3.5(1.5-4.5)' should be:

```
$matches[1] = 3.5
$matches[2] = 1.5
$matches[3] = 4.5
```

Comment: Do you understand the regular expression you're using?

Comment: `(.+?)\((.+?)-(.+?)\)` ... \d is digit only [0-9] not decimal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression.

```
$pattern = '/^(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?)\(((?1))-((?1))\)$/';
```

The first capturing group `( ... )` matches the following pattern:

```
(           # group and capture to \1:
  \d+       #   digits (0-9) (1 or more times)
  (?:       #   group, but do not capture (optional):
    [.,]    #     any character of: '.', ','
    \d+     #     digits (0-9) (1 or more times)
  )?        #   end of grouping
)           # end of \1
```

Afterwords we look for an opening parenthesis and then recurse (*match/capture*) the 1st subpattern followed by a hyphen (`-`) and then recurse (*match/capture*) the 1st subpattern again followed by a closing parenthesis.

<kbd>[**Code Demo**](https://eval.in/205150)</kbd>

Comment: In what way do I have to change the pattern, if I would like to match the string `3.5(2.5-5.5)[10.5]`? In this example `10.5` should be `matches[3]`

Comment: You don't have a string that matches it in the array.

Answer (score -1):

This pattern should help:

```
^(\d+\.?\,?\d+)\((\d+\,?\.?\d+)\-(\d+\.?\,?\d+)\)$
```